# How to search for an object in an arraylist with multiple strings and return opbject?

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

Good afternoon,

I'm new to coding and i need some help
I have created an Arraylist of objects named alHup. alHup contains objects named "Company".

```
private ArrayList<Company> alHup = new ArrayList();
```

Company exists of String ID, String Companytype, String year, String Region, String Class, int Size, int Profit and int Area.

I have Created a separate class to define Company.

```
package aaadblok1.landbouwapp.View;


public class Company {
 private String Companytype, Year, Region, Class;
 private Integer Size, Profit, Area;
 

 
public Company(){
    
}

    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    public void setYear(String Year) {
        this.Year = Year;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return Size;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer Size) {
        this.Size = Size;
    }

    public Integer getArea() {
        return Area;
    }

    public void setArea(Integer Area) {
        this.Area = Area;
    }

    public Integer getProfit() {
        return totaalopbrengst;
    }

    public void setProfit(Integer Profit) {
        this.Profit = Profit;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getClass() {
        return Class;
    }

    public void setClass(String Class) {
        this.Class = Class;
    }

    public String getCompanytype() {
        return Companytype;
    }

    public void setCompanytype(String Companytype) {
        this.Companytype = Companytype;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return Region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String Region) {
        this.Region = Region;
    }
}
```

I have created 4 textfields for String Companytype, String Year, String Region and String Class.
I want to be able to search the Arraylist for a single object that contains the values that are in the 4 textfields and return the int Size, int Profit and int Area for this object . I want to display int Size, int Profit and Int Area in 3 TextFields.

```
txtCompanytype= new TextField();
txtClass= new TextField();
txtRegion= new TextField();
txtYear= new TextField();
txtProfit = new TextField();
txtSize = new TextField();
txtArea= new TextField();
```

I have created a button named Search for this. but I do not know how the lambda expression for the button should look like.

```
Search= new Button("Search");
```

Can anybuddy help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Right now my class looks like this

```
package aaadblok1.landbouwapp;

import aaadblok1.landbouwapp.View.Bedrijfsgroep;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

/**
 *
 * @author potat
 */
public class OverzichtScherm {
 private Label Bedrijftype33, SoKlasse, Regio, Jaar, Totaalopbrengst, Omvang, Oppervlaktecultuurgrond;
 private TextField txtBedrijfstype, txtSoKlasse, txtRegio, txtTotaalopbrengst, txtOmvang, txtOppervlaktecultuurgrond;
 private Button Zoeken, Uitloggen, nh, zh, ut, nb, ze, li, ge , ov, fl, fr, gr, dr, klasse1, klasse2, klasse3, klasse4, klasse5, klasse6, klasse7, klasse8, Groep1, Groep2, Groep3, Groep4, Groep5;
 private GridPane Scherm;
 private  ArrayList<Bedrijfsgroep> alHup = new ArrayList();
 private DataCollector dc = new DataCollector();
 
 public OverzichtScherm(Pane root){
     
 // maken van labels en tekstvelden
 
 Bedrijftype33= new Label("Bedrijfstype:");
 SoKlasse= new Label("So-Klasse:");
 Regio=new Label("Regio:");
Jaar= new Label("Jaar:");
Totaalopbrengst= new Label("Totaal Opbengst:");
Omvang= new Label("Omvang:");
Oppervlaktecultuurgrond= new Label("Oppervlakte Cultuurgrond:");
txtBedrijfstype= new TextField();
txtSoKlasse= new TextField();
txtRegio= new TextField();
txtTotaalopbrengst = new TextField();
txtOmvang = new TextField();
txtOppervlaktecultuurgrond= new TextField();



Scherm= new GridPane();
Scherm.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
Scherm.setHgap(10);
Scherm.setVgap(10);
Scherm.setMinSize(30, 30);
Scherm.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10)); 

//Het maken van de buttons

Zoeken= new Button("Zoeken");
Uitloggen= new Button("Uitloggen");
nh= new Button();
zh= new Button();
ut=new Button();
nb= new Button();
ze= new Button();
li= new Button();
ge= new Button();
ov = new Button();
fl= new Button();
fr= new Button();
gr= new Button();
dr= new Button();
klasse1 = new Button("3.000 tot 25.000 euro");
klasse2= new Button("25.000 tot 100.000 euro");
klasse3= new Button("100.000 tot 250.000 euro");
klasse4= new Button("250.000 tot 500.000 euro");
klasse5= new Button("500.000 tot 1.000.000 euro");
klasse6= new Button("1.000.000 tot 1.500.000 euro");
klasse7=new Button("1.500.000 tot 3.000.000 euro");
klasse8= new Button("meer als 3.000.000 euro");
Groep1=new Button("Akkerbouw");
Groep2=new Button("Tuinbouw");
Groep3=new Button("Blijvende Teelt");
Groep4= new Button("Graasdieren");
Groep5= new Button("Hokdieren");

// bepaalde tekstvlakken niet bewerkbaar zetten (voor gebruiksvriendelijkheid en veiligheid).

txtBedrijfstype.setEditable(false);
txtSoKlasse.setEditable(false);
txtRegio.setEditable(false);
txtTotaalopbrengst.setEditable(false);
txtOppervlaktecultuurgrond.setEditable(false);
txtOmvang.setEditable(false);

//Combobox voor de jaartallen

ComboBox jaartal = new ComboBox();
jaartal.getItems().add("2000JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2001JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2002JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2003JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2004JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2005JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2006JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2007JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2008JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2009JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("20010JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2011JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2012JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2013JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2014JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2015JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2016JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2017JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2018JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2019JJ00");
 jaartal.getItems().add("2020JJ00");



//knoppen programmeren provincies zodat ze de het textvak invullen

nh.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV27");});
zh.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV28");});
ut.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("pv26");});
nb.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV30");});
ze.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV29");});
li.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV31");});
ge.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV25");});
ov.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV23");});
fl.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV24");});
fr.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV20");});
gr.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV21");});
dr.setOnAction(event -> {txtRegio.setText("PV22");});

// knoppen programmeren soklasse zodat het textvak juist wordt ingevuld

klasse1.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029006");});
klasse2.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029007");});
klasse3.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029008");});
klasse4.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029009");});
klasse5.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029010");});
klasse6.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029011");});
klasse7.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029012");});
klasse8.setOnAction(event -> {txtSoKlasse.setText("A029013");});

// knoppen programmeren bedrijfstypen
Groep1.setOnAction(event -> {txtBedrijfstype.setText("A009481");});
Groep2.setOnAction(event -> {txtBedrijfstype.setText("A009487");});
Groep3.setOnAction(event -> {txtBedrijfstype.setText("A009497");});
Groep4.setOnAction(event -> {txtBedrijfstype.setText("A009501");});
Groep5.setOnAction(event -> {txtBedrijfstype.setText("A009510");});

// uitlogknop programmeren, met loguitboodschap
Uitloggen.setOnAction(event ->
{        Alert Loguit = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                Loguit.setTitle("Uitloggen");
                Loguit.setHeaderText("Bedankt en tot ziens!");
                Loguit.showAndWait(); 
                root.getChildren().clear();
                        new LogIn (root);  });

//zoeken knop programmeren zodat de juiste zoektermen worden ingevuld
 ArrayList<Bedrijfsgroep> alHup = dc.getBedrijfsgroep();

Zoeken.setOnAction(event ->{

 });






// Alles op Gridpane zetten en op root


// zoekvakken

Scherm.add(Bedrijftype33, 0,3);
Scherm.add(txtBedrijfstype,1,3);
Scherm.add(SoKlasse, 0,4);
Scherm.add(txtSoKlasse, 1, 4);
Scherm.add(Regio, 0, 5);
Scherm.add(txtRegio, 1, 5);
Scherm.add(Jaar, 0, 6);
Scherm.add(jaartal,1,6);
Scherm.add(Zoeken,1,7);

//UItkomstvakken

Scherm.add(Omvang, 0,10);
Scherm.add(txtOmvang,1,10);
Scherm.add(Oppervlaktecultuurgrond, 0,11);
Scherm.add(txtOppervlaktecultuurgrond, 1, 11);
Scherm.add(Totaalopbrengst, 0,12);
Scherm.add(txtTotaalopbrengst, 1, 12);
Scherm.add(Uitloggen, 1, 13);

//provincies

Scherm.add(nh, 6,3);
Scherm.add(zh, 6,4);
Scherm.add(ut, 6,5);
Scherm.add(nb, 6,6);
Scherm.add(ze, 6,7);
Scherm.add(li, 6,8);
Scherm.add(ge, 6,9);
Scherm.add(ov, 6,10);
Scherm.add(fl, 6,11);
Scherm.add(fr, 6,12);
Scherm.add(gr, 6,13);
Scherm.add(dr, 6,14);

//soklassen

Scherm.add(klasse1, 9,3);
Scherm.add(klasse2, 9,4);
Scherm.add(klasse3, 9,5);
Scherm.add(klasse4, 9,6);
Scherm.add(klasse5, 9,7);
Scherm.add(klasse6, 9,8);
Scherm.add(klasse7, 9,9);
Scherm.add(klasse8, 9,10);

//Bedrijfstypen

Scherm.add(Groep1, 12,3);
Scherm.add(Groep2, 12,4);
Scherm.add(Groep3, 12,5);
Scherm.add(Groep4, 12,6);
Scherm.add(Groep5, 12,7);


root.getChildren().add(Scherm);


     
 }
 
 
    
}
```

Comment: First of all, please write your code names in English, so we know what these variables mean, next you say you created 4 `textfields`, but in your code there are 6 of them, so are you comparing only 4 `textfield` variables or do you compare by all 6 of them?

Comment: Can you clarify the `Strings` and `textfields` please? It does not appear you have a `textfield` for `Jaar`.

Comment: Sorry AP11 and Paul. I have edited the original post to translate the strings and TextFields to English.

Comment: Could you post your `Company` code?

Comment: I have posted the Company class AP11

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. You wish to search a List (of objects) to find an object that meets some criteria? What solutions have you already tried? Are you conversant with "for" and "if"?  (Also - and I understand that commenters have asked for more supporting details - but the question has become quite long.  You might get the most helpful replies if you can condense the question to its essence.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to give you the right answer, if you would provide your whole code, but anyway I would use filters and my lambda would look like this:

```
Optional<Company> result = alHup.stream().filter(company -> company.getCompanyType() == txtCompanytype.getText())
                .filter(company -> company.getYear() == txtYear.getText())
                .filter(company -> company.getRegion() == txtRegion.getText())
                .filter(company -> company.getCompanyClass() == txtClass.getText())
                .findFirst();
 if (result.isPresent()) {
     Company company = result.get();
 }
```

Comment: Hello AP11, I have tried your solution but he says that the company.getYear(), company.getRegion() and company.getCompanyClass do not work. NetBeans cannot find the symbol in the class

Comment: That's because I don't have your code, therefore I expected you to have some kind of `getters`, if you know, what they are. You have to rename them to fit your code.